# Cutting Nails on Chol Hamoed

Tags: yom-tov, chol-hamoed, nail-cutting

Is one allowed to cut nails on Chol Hamoed? what about if it's also erev yom tov (like today)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Per Mishna Berura siman 532 if you do it every Erev Shabbos you are allowed to cut them today.  The Mechaber holds you are allowed to cut your nails on Chol Hamoed no matter what. The Rama adds in that only if it is done for Tevila then it is allowed. the Mishna Berura says if it was done on Erev Yom Tov you are allowed to do it on Chol Hamoed for the last days.

Comment: What if u only do it some shabbosim?

Comment: Like I cut nails every other Erev Shabbos.

Comment: So according to that Rema, and the principle that kol davar shechotzeitz b'tevilah chotzeitz b'netilah (O.C. 161:1), then if you need to do netilas yadayim, would you be allowed to cut your fingernails in order to keep them short?

Answer (score 6):

[Aruch HaShulchan OC 532](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9102&st=&pgnum=205) says if they are in real need of cutting and the reason you did not cut them before Yomtov is because you were too busy with Yomtov preparations  then you may do so on Chol HaMoed (even with a scissor or clipper.)